# How to create JUnit tests for different input files as separate cases?

Tags: java, testing, junit

Right now, I have around 107 test input cases for my interpreter, and I have my JUnit tester set up to manually handle each case independently so as to not lump them all together. That is, if I use a loop to iterate over the test files as such

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TESTS; i++) {
    String fileName = "file_" + (i + 1) + ".in";
    testFile(fileName);
}
```

JUnit will create one giant test result for all 107 tests, meaning if one fails, the entire test fails, which I don't want. As I said, right now I have something like

```
@Test
public static void test001() {
    testFile("file1.in");
}

@Test
public static void test002() {
    testFile("file2.in");
}
```

While this works, I imagine there's a much better solution to get what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@ParameterizedTest` with `@MethodSource` annotations.

For exemple :

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("fileNameSource")
void test(final String fileName) {
    testFile(fileName);
}

private static Stream<String> fileNameSource() {
    return IntStream.range(0,NUM_TESTS).mapToObj(i -> "file_" + (i + 1) + ".in");
}
```

Check the documentation at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

For each params returned by `fileNameSource()`, the corresponding test will be considered as a different case.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define own structure based on your need,
one way to define your input to json file in like list of values as below.

```
{
   [
     "value1",
     "value2"
   ]
}
```

Read this value when you test case execute with the help of `object mapper`.

```
objectMapper.readValue(fixture("filePathName.json"),CustomInput.class);
```

Where CustomInput would be something like below.

```
public class CustomInput {
    List<String> values;
}
```

You can keep increase & decrease your inputs in json.